# Do I need to apply for a design patent if I am applying for a utility patent?

Tags: patentability

I did my own research on a product that I can't find anywhere in the Internet.
Do I need to file for both design and utility at the same time?
Do I file for a patent over seas meaning China at same time?

Comment: Please let us know what jurisdiction you are in (i.e., USA / UK / Canada / Etc.)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer: Not necessarily.**

**Long Answer:**

These conversations are best had with an attorney, but the answer provided gives you a little bit of background. As always there is a ton more consideration that goes into figuring out whether you want to file for a utility and/or design patent. I can only speak to US patent law, but generally speaking a design patent:

> "consists of the visual ornamental characteristics embodied
>   in, or applied to, an article of manufacture. Since a design is
>   manifested in appearance, the subject matter of a design patent
>   application may relate to the configuration or shape of an article, to
>   the surface ornamentation applied to an article, or to the combination
>   of configuration and surface ornamentation. A design for surface
>   ornamentation is inseparable from the article to which it is applied
>   and cannot exist alone. It must be a definite pattern of surface
>   ornamentation, applied to an article of manufacture."

Source: [USPTO](http://www.uspto.gov/patents/resources/types/designapp.jsp#def).

So, it depends on what your product is. If it is a new and useful process, machine, article of manufacture, compositions of matter, or any new useful improvement thereof, you probably want to file a utility patent. If you are trying to protect the ornamental nature of that product you would want to file a design patent as well.

I recommend further reading: [What is the difference between a utility patent and a design patent?](http://www.uspto.gov/main/faq/p120011.htm), and [Design Patent Application Guide](http://www.uspto.gov/patents/resources/types/designapp.jsp).

With respect to filing overseas you have a couple of different options, but you will likely be taking advantage of something called the [Patent Cooperation Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_Cooperation_Treaty). For more information on the PCT check out this short FAQ from the World Intellectual Property Organization: [PCT FAQs](http://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/pct/en/basic_facts/faqs_about_the_pct.pdf).